Aiogram 3. TypeError: 'ChatMemberMember' object is not subscriptable
@dp.message()
async def check_subscribe(mes):
    chat_id = 'id чата'
    user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=mes.from_user.id)
    if user_channel_status['status'] != 'left':
        await mes.answer('Меню:')
        await send_content(mes)
    else:

Выдает ошибку:
if user_channel_status['status'] != 'left':
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: 'ChatMemberMember' object is not subscriptable -
как я могу это исправить?
Нужно чтоб данный кусок кода проверял наличие подписки у юзера. Вроде бы все сделал правильно, но эта ошибка все равно вылезает.
В чем дело?

«Вроде бы все сделал правильно» — непонятно, почему вы решили, что к объекту ChatMemberMember должно быть можно обращаться как к словарю, в документации ничего такого нет

не
if user_channel_status['status'] != 'left':

а
if user_channel_status.status != 'left':

